# Pageviews and events in Google Tag Manager and Google Data Studio

Tags: google-tag-manager, event-tracking, google-data-studio

I set up an event to track time on page after I found out that it wasn't tracked when the page is an exit page. It uses a timer trigger to trigger an event every 15s that reports the number of seconds the user has been on the page.

The action value is the number of seconds the user has been on the page. The goal is to get the highest action value for the tag label per pageview so that I can associate the time on page with a specific pageview.

I tried creating a field in Google Data Studio that get the max value for the event tag using field aggregation.

That got me a max value, but I'm not sure max value per what. Per page path? Per page path if I include the page path in the table? If I try to add pageviews to a table with Page and my custom field, I end up with no data. Attempting to add unique pageviews breaks the table.

I just want a reliable measure of how long users are on the page. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you have the timer trigger happening on all pages? Depending on the site, and how many pages visitors generally tend to visit, and what other events you have setup, you may run into issues as there is a limit of 500 hits per session.

You may want to consider a slightly different approach as suggested by Simo Ahava which takes the hits per session limit into account:

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/fire-trigger-when-user-about-to-leave-page/